# node.js: Error: Cannot find module './Etherio'

Tags: node.js

I'm in the middle of updating my node.js code (http://ushomeautomation.com/Projects/node-irrigation/sched.js , code in question is near the top of the file) and this is my first module which is installed via:

```
npm install --save git+https://git@github.com/linuxha/Etherio.git
```

The Etherio code is in development too. This works:

```
var Etherio = require('/home/njc/dev/irrigation/irrnode/node_modules/Etherio');
```

but this doesn't:

```
var Etherio = require('./Etherio');
```

And what I mean by works is that the code runs and the lights lite up on the etherio board (which is what my module talks to).

```
~/dev/irrigation/irr-sched$ node ./sched.js 
    module.js:329
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module './Etherio'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:355:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:13:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/njc/dev/irrigation/irr-sched/sched.js:70:15)
        at Module._compile (module.js:399:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:406:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:345:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:302:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:431:10)

~/dev/irrigation/irr-sched$ pwd
/home/njc/dev/irrigation/irr-sched
~/dev/irrigation/irr-sched$ ls -la node_modules/Etherio/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 njc njc 4096 Nov 28 19:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 59 njc njc 4096 Nov 28 19:33 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 njc njc 4183 Nov 28 19:33 Etherio.js
-rw-r--r--  1 njc njc 2317 Nov 28 19:33 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 njc njc   90 Nov 28 19:33 README.md
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Linux Debian (3.16.36-1+deb8u1 x86_64)

npm (3.3.12)

node (v5.2.0)

Comment: This appears to be just a path issue.  I don't quite understand your directory structure.  But, `require('./Etherio');` looks for the module in the same directory as the module whose code is currently running and it looks ONLY in that directory.  If Etherio is in `node_modules` below the current module directory, then just use `require('Etherio');`.

Comment: Thanks changing it to require('Etherio'); fixed the problem. I thought the './' told node.js to search the immediate node_modules directory (the Etherio.js is under the node_modules/Etherio directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it solved the issue:

This appears to be just a path issue.

I don't quite understand your directory structure, but `require('./Etherio');` looks for the module in the same directory as the module whose code is currently running and it looks ONLY in that directory (it does not look in the `node_modules` directory below.

If Etherio is in `node_modules` below the current module directory, then just use `require('Etherio');`

Comment: A big thanks for resolving that one for me. I misunderstood the meaning of require('./package') and require('package'). I also voted up the answer but with a low reputation it doesn't show publicly.